# Adding css into a js alert message

Tags: javascript, php, css

I'm trying to add some css into a javascript alert message where alert message will get values to alert from php $_POST[];. Please see the below code

```
$brandname = $_POST["brandname"];

 echo
    "
    <script>
    alert ('Your brand $brandname successfully added into system & redirecting to brand list page');
    window.location='http://localhost/im/carsale/brand_list.php';
    </script>
    ";
```

What I want to do is to add a h1 tag and change the color of `$brandname` value. So could any explain me how to do that.

Comment: You have no control over alert styling, instead set a variable on the redirect, and on the page it hit then show the styled message. what your doing is 1986 style coding.

Comment: You cannot do it with an alert box. But using jQuery UI Dialog you can do the styling

Answer (score 0):

Use this [jquery-confirm](https://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/) library for modern alerts. You can easily style,customize,change behavior them. Most of the websites do NOT use default alert provided by browser using `alert()` function, because they are not customize-able.

This is a simple alert example using [jquery-confirm](https://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/).

```
$.alert({
    title: 'Alert!',
    content: 'Simple alert!',
});
```